# Windows Cache disk to eliminate all drives spinning?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, cache

An initial goal of mine was to run an unRAID server and virtualize Windows within it. A large reason for that was because of the neat "Cache Disk" feature, which allows all writes to be cached on one disk and later flushed to the appropriate disk. Because of my hardware, unRAID wasn't as suitable as I had thought, and so I switched to a raw partition installation of Windows 10 Pro.

Is there a way, through Windows or third party software, that I can designate a cache disk for all of the other mechanical drives in my tower? I have three SSDs that store most of the files I use frequently, and another 4 HDDs for storage of media and important files. Windows likes to spin these up for whatever reason, making my setup louder and consume more power, and I want to have these spun down as often as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have a H87I-PLUS & i7 Core 4790T CPU which enables me to use Intel Smart Response Technology in Rapid Storage Technology (acronym galore) to achieve what you want.

Intel call it "accelerating a drive", but to see this option in the GUI you must satisfy the below system requirements, [more information here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/000005501.html).

```
Intel® Z68, Z87, Q87, H87, Z77, Q77, or H77 Express Chipset-based desktop board
Intel® Core™ Processor in the LGA 1155 or LGA 1150 package
System BIOS with SATA mode set to RAID
Intel RST software 10.5 version release or later
Single hard disk drive or multiple drives in one RAID volume
Solid state drive (SSD) with a minimum capacity of 18.6 GB
Operating system: Windows 8* or Windows* 7 (32-bit and 64-bit editions)
```

I know it says Windows 8 or 7, but mine is currently running Windows 10 Pro no issues.